# Intersection of lists of tuples - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have two lists of tuples both of the form [(a,b),..].

I wish to compare them and get the common elements - but have tried using intersect, but this does not work. Is there a way of using map/filter to output the intersection as a new list of tuples?

Comment: Please show your code, `intersect` should work fine for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a list comprehension:

```
[x | x <- list1, x `elem` list2]
```

Example:

```
Prelude> let list1 = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]
Prelude> let list2 = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,5)]
Prelude> [x | x <- list1, x `elem` list2]
[(1,2),(2,3)]
```

Anyway, `intersect` should work, it works for me:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> list1 `intersect` list2
[(1,2),(2,3)]
```

Comment: Filter would also work: `filter (\`elem\` list2) list1` :)

Comment: In your answer `intersect` compares all elements of the tuple, but I think topic starter wants to find all intersections based on comparison of the first only element of tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Data.Function.on` function to supply function you need to the first (or second) element of the tuple:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (intersectBy)

intersectBy ((==) `on` fst) [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)] [(1,2), (2,3), (3,5)]
> [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

Comment: I guess this returns the matching tuple from the left list. Can we tell something like `intersectBy ((==) \`on\` fst)` and `select (min \`on\` snd)`?